# How to format netbeans php project file to place the html tags in new line?

Tags: html, netbeans, tags, format, indentation

in netbans when i format a code (alt+shift+f) it indents the code in each line but, if two tags are there in the same line, it doesnt keep the other tag in the new line. how to configure in a way that the tags will move to a new line

Thank u